Yarn not found after switching npm version with nvm
I open a terminal and I run:
nvm list

And I get:
          v12.8.0
   ->     v21.7.1

This means that I have 2 versions installed but the active one is v21.7.1
If I run: yarn I get:
yarn install v1.22.22
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
success Already up-to-date.
✨  Done in 0.01s.

So far so good. But for the project I am working on I need v12.8.0so I select that version by running:
nvm use v12.8.0

Now if I run yarn again I get:
zsh: command not found: yarn

If I switch the version back to v21.7.1 yarn will work again. So any idea what is the issue here ?
